# Spring Application startup very slow

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

My application used Spring 3.0.5 + struts 2.3.7 + mybatis 3.2.2, and my environment is Eclipse 3.6 + maven 3.1.1 + jdk 1.7.0.45.

I use `mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=9000` to start the application, and, sometimes(not every time) its startup is very slow, about 15-25 minutes. 
Part of the log are below, `Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext` took 13 minutes. Why?

```
2014-2-19 13:23:24 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.xml]
2014-2-19 13:23:24 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2014-2-19 13:36:22 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
信息: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9000
2014-2-19 13:36:22 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
信息: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9000
```

Comment: Set the logging to trace or debug level and see whats really causing the problem. Post another log than.

Comment: I have tried debug level, nothing is wrong.

Comment: Instead of deploying via maven , have you tried to deploy the war manually ( like making the war file from maven and then manually place it in the webapps directory of tomcat ) ? Does this manual process also result in a slow startup of the application ?

Comment: I use "project--clean" to clean the project, it happened again(not every time). And I turn the MySQL off, it also happened, and there was no error log.